# Capacitors between two batteries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

[image: Circuit]

*The positive terminals of both batteries are supposed to be on the right side*

Here I need to find the potential difference between the parts **a** and **b**.

What I did was I assigned charge $q_1$ to the $2\mu F$ capacitor and $q_2$ to the $4\mu F$ capacitor. By Kirchoff voltage law I get
$12- {{q_2}\over {4}} -24- \frac{q_1}{2}=0$

I don't know how to proceed from here and find the charges, or is there a better way?

Comment: Remember that charge is conserved and you have two capacitors in series.

Comment: But the battery is in the way of the conducting wires, or does it not make a difference?

Comment: @Farcher Will the net EMF be 12 volts?Can you please provide a hint at solving it?

Comment: @user638473 no it should not  as there aren't branches in the circuit

Comment: A battery does not store electric charge, the amount of charge which comes out of one terminal is the same as that which goes into the other terminal.

Comment: @Farcher Yes, I see. So does that means that there is not net charge on the top half, and the bottom one?

Comment: @user638473 For series capacitors the charge is the same on each capacitor. Therefore you can say that $q_{1}=q_{2}$. Vaishakh has it as $q_{1}=-q_{2}$ The interesting thing, however, is that it doesn't seem to matter because for some reason both satisfy KVL. I thought it might be a coincidence based on the circuit parameters. But I varied the  battery voltages and it still held. Hmmm...

Comment: @Farcher See my comment above to the OP. Can you say why it doesn't seem to matter? I checked it a couple of times but found no discrepancy.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an answer to @BobD comment (and the OP's question ) which I cannot write as a comment as I need to refer to a diagram.

Electrically the original diagram can be redrawn as per the middle diagram below which might make it easier to solve the problem?

[image]

The potentials at each of the nodes is shown in the right hand diagram with equal magnitude charges on each of the capacitors.

By convention when one talks about the charge on a capacitor it is the change on the positive plate which is mentioned so in this example $Q_4=Q_2$.